# how to install LIBSVM on PHP (Windows)?

Tags: php, svm, libsvm

Im trying to install libsvm on PHP (windows) like this https://github.com/ianbarber/php-svm.
But im trying a couple of times still fail. can anyone give me detailed tutorial?
im using xampp 1.8.3. PHP version 5.5.15
my error is:

```
 the program can't start because libsvm.dll is missing from your computer
```

```
 PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library E:\xampp\php\ext\php_svm.dll
```

im appreciated if someone can help me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Never done this on Windows and never used xampp before, but the error you are getting is because you need libsvm as well.

The readme in the extension repository that you are using tells you what to do to install it on windows:

> Download latest libsvm, rename Makefile to Makefile.old and
>   Makefile.win to Makefile - nmake  Copy libsvm.lib from libsvm windows
>   directory, and into deps/libs Copy svm.h into includes/libsvm/
>   buildconf configure --disable-all --enable-cli --with-svm=shared nmake
>
> Make sure the libsvm.dll file from the libsvm windows directory in the
>   path when running the resulting lib.

Comment: so i cant install it on xampp?
im just trying copy thos files in this site http://phpir.com/svm/ into ext folder on php folder.

Comment: @user3584131 You have to make sure that libsvm.dll is in the same folder that the extension dll

Comment: @user3584131 did you copy libsvm.dll to E:\xampp\php\ext ?

Comment: yes i did. im already copy libsvm.dll and php_svm.dll in ext folder. but still error. Have you ever tried to install svm in your php?